# bubble sort with pointer in C ,expected declaration or statement at end of input

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I try to implement bubble sort with references the array elements with pointers, rather than using array indexing.

```
void bubble_p(long *, long);

 int main(){

 long count = 10;
 int i;
 long data[]= {5,2,1,7,10,6,8,4,9,0};
 bubble_p(data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(long));
 for(i=0;i<sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);i++){
 printf("%ld\n",data[i]);
}


return 0;

}
void bubble_p(long *data, long count) {
long *last = data + count - 1; 
while (data < last) {    
long *i = data;
while (i < last) { 
    long cur = *i; 
    long next = *(i + 1); 
    if (next < cur) { 
        *i = next; 
        *(i + 1) = cur; 
    }
   i++;
}
last--;
}
}
```

Edited: Now the code works perfectly

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. That is, provide the `main` and any other code needed so that anyone can take the code *exactly* as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of this is, because using array syntax would compile to the exact same code (sans bugs) and would be more readable.  Seems like a case of premature optimization.

Comment: We need to see the calling code to see if count matches data.

Comment: You are currently missing a close brace `}` at the end of `bubble_p()`.  Systematic indentation would help you spot that problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I have edited the code as you suggested. Now it runs perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing count of 10 when the array only has 5 elements?

As declared, it will allocate 5 elements and throw away the rest of your initializer data.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
long data[]= {5,2,1,7,10,6,8,4,9,0};
bubble_p(data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(long));
```

Let the compiler figure out how big to make the array, and rather than hardcoding the size, let the compiler figure that out too.

Comment: The superfluous initializers must generate a compiler warning — the program should fail to compile.

Comment: In my tests, gcc does give a warning for each excess initializer, but warnings do not cause it to fail to compile by default.

Comment: Use `-Werror` with GCC; then you won't be tempted to run buggy code.

Comment: Some prefer `sizeof(*data)` over `sizeof(long)`. I prefer a macro so there's no repetition.

Comment: While it is very annoying to me some developers release code that still gives warnings and I wish they did use `-Werror`, just because it has warnings doesn't mean it is buggy.  But every warning is a *potential* bug.

Comment: @user10489 I modify the data as you suggested. Now I got the error `expected declaration or statement at end of input`